# Given $y(0)=y(1)=0,~|y'(x)|<1$ for $0\le x\le 1$ is it true that $\int_0^1\frac1{(1+y')^2}dx\ge 1$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, calculus-of-variations

> Q1. Given $y(0)=y(1)=0,~|y'(x)|<1$ for $0\le x\le 1$ is it true that $\int_0^1\frac1{(1+y')^2}dx\ge 1$?

I checked this for 2 functions

$y(x)=\frac{a}\pi \sin\pi x,~|a|<1,~\int_0^1\frac1{(1+y')^2}dx=\frac1{(1-a^2)^{3/2}}$,

$y(x)=a x(1-x),~|a|<1,~\int_0^1\frac1{(1+y')^2}dx=\frac1{1-a^2}$,

but couldn't find any counterexamples or the proof.

I'm also interested in this question

> Q2. Given $y(0)=y(1)=0,~y'(x)>-1$ for $0\le x\le 1$ is it true that $\int_0^1\frac1{(1+y')^2}dx\ge 1$?

Comment: And what about your own examples with $a=0$?

Comment: @ProfessorVector , thanks for pointing that out, I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A1. The function $\varphi(s) := \dfrac{1}{(1+s)^2}$ is convex in $(-1, +\infty)$.
By Jensen's inequality we have that
$$
\int_0^1 \varphi(y'(x))\, dx \geq \varphi\left(\int_0^1 y'(x)\, dx\right)
= \varphi(0) = 1.
$$

A2. See A1.